# abstract inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, visual-studio-2015, abstract-class, subclassing

I'm working on an assignment that will allow the user to purchase tickets for a few different types of events. I have to use a class for tickets that can't be instantiated, with a subclass for each of the specific types of ticket.

I've run in to my first snag, which is that the parameters on the base constructor for the subclass is giving me an error "An object reference is required for non-static field"

Here is the base class

```
abstract class Ticket
{
    public int ticketcount;
    public double ticketprice;

    public Ticket()
    {
        ticketcount = 0;
        ticketprice = 0;
    }

    public Ticket(int ticketcount, double ticketprice)
    {
        this.ticketcount = ticketcount;
        this.ticketprice = ticketprice;
    }

}
```

and here is the subclass.

```
class PlayTicket : Ticket
{
    public PlayTicket() : base()
    {

    }

    public PlayTicket(string sn) : base(ticketcount, ticketprice)
    {

    }
}
```

the error is occurring on the line

```
public PlayTicket(string sn) : base(ticketcount, ticketprice)
```

where the variables "ticketcount" and "ticketprice" are. How would I best be able to get around this? Or am I completely misunderstanding how and why to use a non-instatiatable class?

Comment: Well where do you expect it to get `ticketcount` and `ticketprice` from? You're constructing a new object. You should probably have those as extra parameters. (Additionally, you should use `ticketCount` and `ticketPrice` as names, and probably use `decimal` instead of `double` as the price type.)

Comment: What are you trying to do with `public PlayTicket(string sn) : base(ticketcount, ticketprice)`?
You need to provide values for parameters of the base constructor, like
`public PlayTicket(string sn) : base(1, 25)`

Comment: Shouldn't it work since PlayTicket extends from Ticket? The book we're using demonstrates it working this way.

Comment: Oh wait a second. I think I understand now. So those parameters are getting their values from the new object in the program, and then passing it up to the base class to be handled in calculation?

Comment: Some additional critiques: First **never** public fields in an abstract base class. Either protected fields, or virtual properties. Second, `ticketcount` is (1) redundant; it's in a class called `Ticket`, no need to repeat that, and (2) wait a minute, tickets don't have "counts" in the first place. I have bought hundreds of tickets in my life and not one had a "count" on it.  If you are representing a *purchase order*, then don't call it `Ticket`.  Third, always use `decimal` for prices, never `double`. Use doubles for physical quantities like height or speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call parent constructor child constructor, you should pass argument value from child constructor to parent constructor.

You child constructor should be like this :

```
public PlayTicket(string sn, int ticketcount,double ticketprice) : base(ticketcount, ticketprice)
{

}
```

This way, `ticketcount` and `ticketprice` goes to parent constructor and initialize accordingly.

When creating new object of PlayTicket, you should do :

```
Ticket playTicket = new PlayTicket("mySN", 20, 200);
```

As JonSkeet suggested in the comment that you should use decimal for money value.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor to the derived class `PlayTicket` should probably have `ticketcount` and `ticketprice` as parameters, fx:

```
public PlayTicket(string sn, int ticketcount, double ticketprice) : base(ticketcount, ticketprice)
{
  //...
}
```